# Is Infragistics Ignite UI 2014.2 (14.2.20142.1024) compatible with jquery 1.10.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics

On the official NuGet page, ignite ui 2014.2 is listed as requiring jquery 2.0.3 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/IgniteUI.Trial/14.2.20142.1024).

Unfortunately we need to use it in an app that supports IE8. The 1.x jquery version equivalent to jquery 2.0.3 is jquery 1.10.2.

Has anyone tried to use infragistics 2014.2 with jquery 1.10.2?
Can we reliably use jquery 1.10.2 without breaking ignite ui functionality?

According to the jquery blog, the public apis of jquery 1.10.2 and 2.0.3 should be in sync.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer is yes, we also asked this question on the infragistics forum and they answered: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/93410/462039.aspx#462039

From the referenced answer:

> Our Supported Environments page lists that jQuery 1.11.1 is compatible with IgniteUI 14.2.  This would cover jQuery 1.10.2 as well and IgniteUI is expected to function under jQuery 1.10.2 just as equally.  If you encounter any issues using IgniteUI 14.2 with jQuery 1.10.2, please let us know and we will investigate them.
>
> Thank you for pointing out that the NuGet page is showing these requirements.  I am bringing this up with our product management team.